# bitcoin-python API not receiving funds

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain.info

I've just started toying around with the bitcoind Python wrapper ([bitcoin-python](http://laanwj.github.io/bitcoin-python/doc/usage.html)) and have run into some issues when trying to move funds around.

On the client side, I have generated a new address, via

```
new_addr = conn.getnewaddress(ACCT)
```

Upon calling

```
conn.getaddressesbyaccount(ACCT)
```

I see `new_addr` within the addresses listed.

I now send a test transaction (~1mBTC) on blockchain.info to `new_addr`, and have waited for some period of time, so that there is at least one confirmation in the chain.

However, upon calling

```
amount_received = btc_conn.getreceivedbyaddress(new_addr)
```

I have not received any coins at that address.

Furthermore, when attempting to find out more information about the transaction via

```
btc_conn.gettransaction(tx_id)
```

where `tx_id` is given in `blockchain.info/tx/tx_id`, I'm getting an `InvalidAddressOrKey` error.

Is there there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also another possibility, that's that you haven't yet downloaded all the block chain with bitcoind.

If you haven't yet started the daemon you must use this command:

```
bitcoind -daemon
```

Then, you can use the command:

```
bitcoind getblockcount
```

To check the number of blocks that the daemon has already downloaded, and compare it with the [lastest block number](http://blockexplorer.com/)

Your transaction is on the lastest blocks, so you must wait it to be completed, and this can take many hours.

Comment: This was indeed the issue -- after a week I checked back and everything was fine. If only I had gigabit back then :)

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that your transaction has still zero confirmations, that might be the reason it doesn't show in **getreceivedbyaddress()**, which by default only returns transactions that have at least one confirmation. To override this, call it like this: **getreceivedbyaddress(address, 0)**.

Also note that **gettransaction()** will only work for in-wallet transactions, for other transactions it will just throw an exception. Try calling it for an older transaction of yours and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in block.io or blockchain.info that your transaction goes through?

Furthermore `gettransaction()` doesn't work unless you have `txindex=1`in your `bitcoin.conf settings`.

Look here for inspiration:

http://cryptoassetscore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends.html#module-cryptoassets.core.backend.bitcoind

Also if you are accepting Bitcoin payments in Python, [check out cryptoassets.core library for Bitcoin cryptocurrencies in Python](https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets). (disclaimer: I am the author)